# What technology is used by Laravel (or Bootstrap) for his documentation?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, static, documentation, mkdocs

Laravel (or Bootstrap) hosts his documentation on GitHub with markdown files. I cannot find what system they use to generate their online documention. Is it Mkdocs, or something else ?

Comment: laravel's website is a laravel app that uses a markdown parsers, they cache the parsed html and have a documentation view to display the content ...